# PlayStore URL of an application displays App's PackageName or its ApplicationId?

Tags: android

Does PlayStore URL to any particular application, display the application's **PackageName** or its **ApplicationId**?

Comment: just read this official document and everything will be crystal clear to you  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Answer (score 1):

Application id.

A long long time ago, there wasn't the concept of `applicationId` in android and the package name was used instead.

Today, we use `applicationId`, but sometimes they're used interchangeably.

Perhaps you're reading old documentation or a document that uses both to refer to the same thing.